# select option doesnt work with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to change  style with jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#tmadrp').click(function(){
            if($('#tmadrp option:selected').val().toString()=='theme1')
            {
                $('link[href="style1"]').remove();
                $('head').append('<link type="text/css" href="syle2"/>')
            }
});
```

but this doesnt react.How can I do.
thanks.

Comment: You are missing a closing `});`. What do you mean by "this"? Are you sure that you are looking for the value and not the text of the option?

Comment: If you format your code like that I'm not surprised he missed the closing tags ;)

Comment: `.toString()` is redundant in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

A more proper way to do this would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tmadrp').on('click', function(){
        if ($.trim( this.value ) == 'theme1' ) {
            $('link[href="style1"]')[0].disabled = true;
            var link = $('<link />', {type: 'text/css', href: 'syle2'});
            $('head').append(link);
        }
    });
});
```

You do know you've written 'syle2' and not 'style2', and that removing a stylesheet does'nt remove the styles as they are already loaded ?

Comment: +1, however, there are a couple of things here that won't work in IE7.

Comment: thank you my friend but your code didnt work too.I want to say what I want to do again:in index.php Iam using for css style stil1.css.And I put a select option on index.php why users can change the style of the page.Options are tema1,tema2,tema3.When user click tema1 ,style file will be change.Thank you again,I wish I accomplish this.